# jQuery Scroll to Div

Tags: jquery, html

I am making an FAQ page and have buttons across the top to jump to a category (it jumps to the `p` tag that I use as the category label, ex. `<p id="general">` for my general category).
Instead of just jumping right to the category, I want to add a scroll effect.  I want something like http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex3/scrolltop.htm that scrolls to the desired part of my page.  That link is a script that goes to the top of the page with a nice scrolling effect.  I need something similar that will scroll to where I link to.  For example, if I want to go to a misc. category, I want to just be able to have `<a href="#misc">Miscellaneous</a>` and have it scroll to that section of the page.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Check this link: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ for a demo, I've used it before and it works quite nicely.

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't for the 15 characters minimum comment I would've commented on yours with: Snap! :P

Comment: This script is the winner, but I don't know whose to choose!

Comment: Well, seeing as I was first (by 15 seconds), I guess I deserve a win? :P As a token of gratitude I'll upvote symmet's answer for some extra rep...

Comment: Guys, what about my (related but unjustly downvoted) question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400107/jquery-bring-a-div-into-viewport maybe you will have some insight ?

Comment: @xaccrocheur it was indeed unjustly downvoted. I posted a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: sorry noob question. but what does this do? `if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {`

Comment: at least on jquery v1.12.4, the hash character on selector needs to be escaped like this: `$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])')`

Answer (score 129):

It is **often** required to move both body and html objects together.

```
$('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#divToBeScrolledTo").offset().top
});
```

ShiftyThomas is right:

```
$("#divToBeScrolledTo").offset().top + 10 // +10 (pixels) reduces the margin.
```

So to increase the margin use:

```
$("#divToBeScrolledTo").offset().top - 10 // -10 (pixels) would increase the margin between the top of your window and your element.
```

Comment: No semicolon here `.offset().top;`

Comment: Should it not be minus 10 for a 10px margin at the top?    .offset().top - 10

Comment: If you want to control the speed of scrolling, just add an duration (in ms) parameter (number as int or string) to the animate function: $('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#divToBeScrolledTo").offset().top
}, 2000);

Answer (score 28):

Something like this would let you take over the click of each internal link and scroll to the position of the corresponding bookmark:

```
$(function(){
  $('a[href^=#]').click(function(e){
    var name = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
    var pos = $('a[name='+name+']').offset();
    $('body').animate({ scrollTop: pos.top });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Pardon my stupidity, but could someone please translate this answer into English?

Comment: @Imray: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: The general idea. What does `$('a[href^=#]')` mean? And what about `$('a[name='+name+']')`? Also, how did you figure out to do it this way? I'd like to learn to learn as well :)

Answer (score 27):

Could just use JQuery position function to get coordinates of your div, then use javascript scroll:

```
var position = $("div").position();
scroll(0,position.top);
```

Answer (score 9):

if the link element is:

```
<a id="misc" href="#misc">Miscellaneous</a>
```

and the Miscellaneous category is bounded by something like:

```
<p id="miscCategory" name="misc">....</p>
```

you can use jQuery to do the desired effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#misc").click(function() {
    $("#miscCategory").animate({scrollTop: $("#miscCategory").offset().top});
  });
</script>
```

as far as I remember it correctly.. (though, I haven't tested it and wrote it from memory)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#misc").click(function() {
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: $("#miscCategory").offset().top});
  });
</script>

Comment: I have tried a multitude (and I mean a multitude) of methods to programmatically force a scroll to top of a div inside a modal window. All failed. This one did the trick! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same. Saw an example using this:
https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

I use it as follows:

```
$('#arrow_back').click(function () {
    $.scrollTo('#features_1', 1000, { easing: 'easeInOutExpo', offset: 0, 'axis': 'y' }); 
});
```

Clean solution. Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

The script below is a generic solution that works for me. It is based on ideas pulled from this and other threads.

When a link with an href attribute beginning with "#" is clicked, it scrolls the page smoothly to the indicated div. Where only the "#" is present, it scrolls smoothly to the top of the page.

```
$('a[href^=#]').click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    if (target == '#')
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 600);
    else
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 100
    }, 600);
});
```

For example, When the code above is present, clicking a link with the tag `<a href="#">` scrolls to the top of the page at speed 600. Clicking a link with the tag `<a href="#mydiv">` scrolls to 100px above `<div id="mydiv">` at speed 600. Feel free to change these numbers.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I should remove line 2: `event.preventDefault();`. By this rule the anchor is not added to the url (in your address-bar). So, if someone copies the page.... You get it? ;) By removing that line it's fixed. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, that's better. Thank you. That line was also preventing the script from working in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 'name' instead of 'href' for a cleaner url:

```
    $('a[name^=#]').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('name');
    if (target == '#')
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 600);
    else
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 100
    }, 600);
});
```