# Auto scroll to a div after finish loading. Use jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with id=now, this div is empty and do not have any css property (no width, no height, just a hidden div). I want when browser finish load the page, then scroll to this div immediately. User do not need to click on some thing.

Here is my html

```
<html>
<div>Long div Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="now"></div>
<div>Long div Lorem ipsum</div>
```

How to do this with jquery ?

Comment: Duplicate question - check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: see in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284814/jquery-scroll-to-div

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(function() { // when the DOM is ready...
    //  Move the window's scrollTop to the offset position of #now
    $(window).scrollTop($('#now').offset().top);
});
```