# JQuery: scroll element into viewport

Tags: jquery, html

I want to do the opposite of "[Scroll to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284814/jquery-scroll-to-div)" : That is, instead of scrolling to a div, I want the div to scroll to me. "Me" being one of the following rows (twitter bootstrap `row`) :

```
+-------------+-----------+   +-------------+-----------+ 
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+---click-----+   div     |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+-----------+   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+-----------+
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +---click-----+    div    |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+           |   +-------------+           |
+-------------+-----------+   +-------------+-----------+
```

See, when I click on one of the lower left rows, the viewport scrolls to the content div. I want the opposite : I want this div (a twitter bootstrap `col-nn` created on the fly, than *can* semantically "slide" inside its own tall container) to scroll into place.

So the `row` will have to, on click, somehow detect that the `div` is out of sight. This [seems](http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-test-if-element-is-in-viewport-visible-on-screen) possible ; but what about the moving div part?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Row title</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr class="my_row">
            <td>row</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="my_row">
            <td>row</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="my_row">
            <td>row</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="my_row">
            <td>row</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="my_row">
            <td>row</td>
          </tr>
<!-- a lot of other rows -->        
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div> <!-- col-md-8 -->

    <div id="details" class="col-md-4 details">
      <div>THIS IS THE DIV</div>
    </div> <!-- col-md-4 -->

  </div> <!-- col-sm-12 -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can post `html` , `js` ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I did read your question 5 times and still not understand what it is you are trying to do, so that may be a reason.

Comment: No one seem to understand what I'm talking about ; Apparently those who killed this question don't know anything about web design / Ergonomy - I do it by trade since the beggining) I'm going to do it anyway, without your help, or the opposite for that matter. Morons.

Comment: I understood exactly what you wanted in your question. This recent spat of downvotes on perfectly valid questions is quite disconcerting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I constructed this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eo5usms8/) to illustrate how you might achieve something like what you stated, that is if I understood correctly what you wanted. I used a CSS3 transition to facilitate the actual animation, which gets triggered because of the 0ms timeout in changing the "top" property of the `DIV`. In the sample I provided, I aligned the top of the `DIV` to the top of the row that was clicked. Obviously, you can change it to float in the center if you wish (by doing some mathemagics).

Hope it points you in the right direction!

**HTML**

As supplied in your question...

**CSS**

```
#details {
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#details").css("top", $(".my_row:first").offset().top);
    $(".my_row").click(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#details").css("top", row.offset().top);
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is pure genius. Not only did you understand my problem, but you provided a simple and elegant solution. Sir, you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: `row.offset().top` worked better that `offset()`. This is *really* cool.

Comment: You could also change the `click` event to a `hover` event to let the `DIV` track your mouse as you hover over the various rows, as per updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/eo5usms8/1/