# Implementation of jQuery 'animate' with Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm currently learning to use Meteor, and am having trouble implementing the jQuery 'animate' function in one of my templates. I'm using this great boilerplate https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-boilerplate as an example, and am trying to get the following working:

**home.html**

```
<template name="home">

    <div id="front-page">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="page-bottom-nav">
           <div class="row">
              {{#each feature}}
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail aligned center home-page-nav-boxes">
                    <a href="{{path}}" class="link unstyled no-underline {{color}} padding wrapper">
                        <i class="glyphicon {{glyphicon}} image-links-home-page"></i>
                      <div class="headline text-links-home-page">{{text}}</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>

  <div id="about">
    About
  </div>
  <div id="explore">
    Explore
  </div>
  <div id="blog">
    Blog
  </div>
  <div id="press-contact">
    Press/Contact
  </div>


</template>
```

**home.js**

```
    Template.home.helpers({
      'feature' : function () {
        return [
          { 'text' : 'About', 'glyphicon' : 'glyphicon-sunglasses', 'color' : 'hover-yellow', 'path' : '#about' },
          { 'text' : 'Explore', 'glyphicon' : 'glyphicon-road', 'color' : 'hover-red', 'path' : '#explore' },
          { 'text' : 'Blog', 'glyphicon' : 'glyphicon-pencil', 'color' : 'hover-blue', 'path' : '#blog' },
          { 'text' : 'Press/Contact', 'glyphicon' : 'glyphicon-envelope', 'color' : 'hover-green', 'path' : '#press-contact' }
        ];
      },
    });

    Template.home.events ({

    });

    Template.home.rendered = function () {

        // @see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284814/jquery-scroll-to-div
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function (event) {
        alert("Content has been clicked");
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          console.log(target);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(target.offset().top);
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
          return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
    });
  };
```

**home.less**

```
@import 'base';


#main {
    .image-links-home-page.glyphicon {
        font-size: @font-size-giant;
    }

    .hover-yellow:hover {
        color: yellow;
    }

    .hover-green:hover {
        color: green;
    }

    .hover-red:hover {
        color: red;
    }

    .hover-blue:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

    #front-page {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url('images/mt-cook.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: fixed;
        position: relative;
    }

    .page-bottom-nav {
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 90%;
        padding-left: @padding-enormous-horizontal;
        padding-right: @padding-enormous-horizontal;
    }

    .home-page-nav-boxes {
        padding: @padding-giant-vertical;
        opacity: 0.6;
        transition: 0.7s color;
    }

    .text-links-home-page {
        font-size: @font-size-large;
        padding-top: @padding-large-vertical;
    }

    .navbar.past-front-page {
        background-color:#fff;
        color:#444;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    #about {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #explore {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }

    #blog {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #press-contact {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: green;
    }

}
```

These files are all in the `client` folder within my app tree. The `console.log` and `alert` debugs work as expected, but no scrolling takes place...
Thanks in advance for the help, and do let me know if I'm missing something completely here!

Comment: Template.home.rendered = function () {  -->  **}** ??

Comment: Nice spot - it is there in my code, just missed it on transferring to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was to do with 100% sizing of the `<html>` and `<body>` tags. With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window?rq=1) and a good overview of these tags and their behaviour [here](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html), the scroll now works as expected. Note that calling the function in either `Template.home.events` or `Template.home.rendered` works here.

Answer (score 0):

remove rendered function and use **Template.home.events;**

**try**

**home.html**

```
<body>
    {{> home}}
</body>

<template name="home">

    <div id="front-page">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="page-bottom-nav">
           <div class="row">
              {{#each feature}}
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail aligned center home-page-nav-boxes">
                    <a href="{{path}}" class="link unstyled no-underline {{color}} padding wrapper">
                        <i class="glyphicon {{glyphicon}} image-links-home-page"></i>
                      <div class="headline text-links-home-page">{{text}}</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
           </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>

  <div id="about" style="height:500px">
    About
  </div>
  <div id="explore" style="1000px">
    Explore
  </div>
  <div id="blog" style="height:750px">
    Blog
  </div>
  <div id="press-contact">
    Press/Contact
  </div>


</template>
```

**home.js**

```
Template.home.helpers({
      'feature' : function () {
        return [
          { 'text' : 'About', 'glyphicon' : 'glyphicon-sunglasses', 'color' : 'hover-yellow', 'path' : '#about' },
          { 'text' : 'Explore', 'glyphicon' : 'glyphicon-road', 'color' : 'hover-red', 'path' : '#explore' },
          { 'text' : 'Blog', 'glyphicon' : 'glyphicon-pencil', 'color' : 'hover-blue', 'path' : '#blog' },
          { 'text' : 'Press/Contact', 'glyphicon' : 'glyphicon-envelope', 'color' : 'hover-green', 'path' : '#press-contact' }
        ];
      },
});

Template.home.events({
  'click a[href^="#"]': function(event, template) {
    var $target = $(event.currentTarget.hash);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

see demo http://questions-29109608.meteor.com

Comment: Thanks, but no joy I'm afraid...I can pick up the target variable in the console, but .animate doesn't fire

Comment: Hmmm, that works perfectly...just not in my app! I wonder if it's a conflict with one of the packages I have installed - any thoughts?

Comment: No, remove rendered function and use Template.home.events.