# Auto scroll to new div

Tags: javascript, scroll

When i click on a radio button, a new div, "resultat3" shown.

I want an automatic scroll down to the new div, when it is loaded.

```
function stateChanged7()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
   {
     document.getElementById("resultat3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = showDiv4(1);
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#resultat3").offset().top
});
```

Very similar to this already answered question. Hope it helps.

[jQuery Scroll to Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284814/jquery-scroll-to-div)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That makes sense, apologies :)

Comment: No problem. If you add more information from the link to your question, chances are it won't be flagged as low-quality and possibly removed.

Comment: If using jQuery, do it this way. It will scroll smoothly to your div.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by **jquery .focus() method**

Suppose your new div have id show then after putting data you can use,

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#show').offset().top);
```

It will focus or scroll to new div.

Comment: If you need scroll down to focus for div you can use above code. i have edited the answer, you can check this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
function stateChanged6()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
  {
    document.getElementById("resultat2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = showDiv4(1);
    $("#resultat2").focus();
  }
}
```

tested with:

```
$("resultat2").focus();
```