# How to create scrollbar in jQuery-mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

- **What I want to do:**

Is creating a scrollbar in jquery mobile.

- **What I have :**

I have a body & a scroll bar like this:

[image: ]]

- **How I want to do it :**

There are three divs (pink one,red one & grey one) and I have added a class to the red div named: *"scroll"*
I have created two events: swipe up & swipe down, and they are used like this:

```
$('.scroll').on('swipedown',function(){alert("swipedown detected");} );
$('.scroll').on('swipeup',function(){alert("swipeup detected");} );
```

Now I want to write some codes that instead of alerting *"swipe detected"* they really scroll down or up the page.

- **What I have written so far :**

I really tried to give you a *JSFiddle link*, but some errors happened.
But in this [link](http://qeshmbook.com/test_scroll.html) you can see the demo , and view the source code.

***Anyway how can I write a function that scrolls up or down the page?***

Comment: have you tried the jquery animate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284814/jquery-scroll-to-div

Comment: Tnx , but I dont want to scroll to a specific part, I want to create a scrollbar