# jQuery open bootstrap tab and go to part of page within tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap tabs on my page one of which contains comments, I've used a script to allow me to open the tab by adding #comments_tab to the URL which works fine but if i want to goto a specific comment within the tab is there a way to do it?

I can't seem to use two hash tags like #comments_tab#post-12345

If the tab is already open and i add #post-12345 it goes to the comment i just need a way to combine opening the tab and going to the comment.

This is the script for opening the tab

```
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  hash && $('ul.nav a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use javascript to move the page down to the post hash location after opening the comments tab? No need to feed it to the browser URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284814/jquery-scroll-to-div

Comment: @cale_b yes that is what i'm looking for, I will have a read through see if i can figure out how to implement it, thanks.

Comment: @cale_b i still think i have the same issue as i can't do both things open the tab and then scroll down to the hash location, I added the script from the link you sent but it only scrolls down to the comment when i manually open the tab.